# Which AMD/ATI cards don't require non-free firmware when using radeon?

Tags: hardware, graphics, radeon, free-software

Which AMD/ATI video cards don't require non-free firmware when using the `radeon` driver?

[`nouveau` has a convenient matrix](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/) showing which cards are supported without having to use non-free firmware (card families not tagged as **EXTFW**). Is there an equivalent table for radeon?

I've looked at [`radeon`'s similar feature matrix page](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/) but wasn't able to ascertain this information.

According to [Debian's AtiHowTo page](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Firmware):

> Proprietary, binary-only firmware (aka microcode) was removed from the Debian kernel's radeon DRM driver in linux-2.6 2.6.29-1, to resolve Debian bug 494009.
>
> The firmware can be provided by installing the [`firmware-amd-graphics`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-amd-graphics) or [`firmware-linux-nonfree`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-linux-nonfree) package.
>
> Without this package installed, poor 2D/3D performance in the radeon driver is commonly experienced.
>
> Some GPUs **may** require firmware to operate the X Window System, or do dual display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information on the [Beyond Linux From Scratch](http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/firmware.html) site, it seems that all ATI/AMD GPUs require firmware blobs.