# How to use a 4K monitor with 60Hz and HDMI 2 on Debian/KDE with onboard graphics / only free graphics drivers?

Tags: debian, kde, graphics, monitors, hdmi

I have a 4K monitor capable of 60 Hz with HDMI 2.

I have it connected to my machine with the 60Hz-capable cable that came with the monitor.

However, in the Display options of KDE the highest Refresh rate is 30.00 Hz, and not 60 Hz (it's currently set to auto). The display options display that it's using HDMI 1, and not HDMI 2.

I also looked through all the settings of my monitor.

I currently don't have a graphics card installed, mainly because [my graphics card doesn't seem to really work with free graphics card divers (the nouveau driver in my case) even though it looks like it should according to a website about nouveau](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584251/233262). I'm running latest Debian10 with KDE.

Maybe the cvt or xrandr commands could be used for this somehow - if so: how to know which? And if 60 Hz support can be added why is configuring it not an option in the KDE settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't have a graphics card installed"? That you're using an integrated GPU? If so, are you sure that your motherboard/laptop supports HDMI 2 on the output? A lot of recent hardware still doesn't (typically because the primary focus is on DisplayPort and HDMI is often included just by way of its compatibility with DisplayPort, which is limited to HDMI 1).

Comment: Exactly, I'm using onboard graphics card. I looked up the specs and found that it supports 60 Hz only at a lower resolution, I checked it in the Display settings and could set it to 60 Hz when lowering the resolution (with HDMI 1, not HDMI 2 though). However, that's not what I'd like to do and it looks like I need to somehow resolve this other question about which graphics cards work with free software / how to get my graphics card to run with nouveau resolved instead. I think I'll delete or close this question.